# Where I can find a table of pairs of colors (primary and accent) for Material Design?

Tags: material-design

I noticed that Google uses standard pair of colors (main and accent). For example, Indigo-500 and Pink-A200; Pink-500 and Yellow-A200 and so on. Is there a table of pairs of colors?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors are listed on the Angular Material site, and should correspond to what you are asking.  [Angular Material Theme Introduction and Color Lists](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/Theming/01_introduction). Also, the [Material Design Lite site](http://www.getmdl.io/customize/index.html) has a color selection wheel.